# I would like to display the div only once - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

### catch is that

I would like to display the div only once, not three times:

```
//angular js code

$scope.arr=["sunday","mpnday","tuesday"];

//html view

<ul>
<li ng-repeat="x in arr">
  <div><p>{{ x }}</p>
  </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `<div>` inside `li` not good

Comment: why not just remove `div`?

Comment: i want to achieve it as given above,,<div> should compulsary within <li>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="x in arr">
  <div ng-if="$first">
      <p>{{ x }}</p>
  </div>
  <p ng-if="!$first">{{ x }}</p>
</li>
</ul>
```

Anyway, I would recommend you to rewrite your markup in valid way. `div` inside `li` is quite bad markup style.